# Is it a good practice to place secondary methods in separate class and use it like class methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, architecture

Is it a good practice to place handy functions in separate class and then use it as class methods?

For example:

Declare method `+ (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)unresizedImage;` in class `MyTools` and then use it like `something = [MyClass resizeImage:myImage];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping "utility" methods into a specific class is a common practice to reduce code duplication and adhere to the DRY principle. In an instance as you described above you could create a category on UIImage to allow image resizing. This would make it available to every instance of UIImage. I prefer to use categories in cases like this where every instance of a UIImage could benefit from resizing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Its really a good practice to create a separate class for Utilities methods. 
This makes redundancy of code.
Code is not repeated.
You can use the same class in any other project also.

If, you can also create categories and add methods as you want.

It's one of good coding practice.